# How do you retrieve the id of an object out of an array stored in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, firebase, javascript-objects

I'm working on a relatively simple card catalog project. It takes a bunch of inputs from a form and displays them collected on individual cards.

The inputs create an object, and each object is pushed into the database with `firebase.database().ref('/Book').push(const formed from constructor);`

So then the database looks like this:

```
project-library-7e667
    - Book
        - MDXCUa-3s5yX-Iv8u7X
            contrib: "Me"
            fname: "Albert"
            lname: "Camus"
            own: false
            pubDate: "1942"
            title: "L'Etranger"
```

On each card is the option to remove it, or change the value of `own` to "true" via a checkbox.

Is there a name for a shorthand/reference/variable/notation for the thing that is `MDXCUa-3s5yX-Iv8u7X`?

I can't use the name itself because obviously it would change with each card. I suppose I could just overwrite the entire array with each change, but I think understanding this issue would be better.

I would also like to pull from the database to redraw each card when the project is refreshed, so it would be nice to know if these objects had ways of referencing them.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to be able to get that key Id so in your application your can use that key id to remove/edit/update correct doc right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okej, What you want to do is get the Key of the document before you do `.data()`

so something like this :

```js
const db = firebase.firestore();
const ref = db.collection('books').get()

ref.forEach(doc=> {
    const book = {
        id: doc.id,
        author: doc.data().author,
        body: doc.data().body,
        title: doc.data().title,
        starCount: doc.data().starCount,
        authorPic: doc.data().authorPic
    }
    //set your state here with the "book" object
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Still struggling with this, I had been using the real-time database instead of firestore. I might have to post again.

Answer (score -1):

From the docs...

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

```
function writeNewPost(uid, username, picture, title, body) {
  // A post entry.
  var postData = {
    author: username,
    uid: uid,
    body: body,
    title: title,
    starCount: 0,
    authorPic: picture
  };

  // Get a key for a new Post.
  var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;

  // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
  var updates = {};
  updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
  updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```

Comment: That is not what the author asked for. The author wanted a way to get the key not to create new

Comment: The return value from `push` has the object reference available hence the key.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push

Comment: `var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;`

Comment: What the author wants is the current Key Id of the documents that exist on firebase. The author does not want to know the key Id before pushing to firestore.

Comment: Then answer the question smarty pants. It doesn't matter either way. If you have the key before or after the document is created.

Comment: Smartypants? Why this approach is not a good way to do it is because the ID can be changed. Say that the author allows the user to write to the document. Then the user can overwrite the ID and then you already have the ID of the document when you are fetching it so no need to add another key with the ID when the document already has an id. Why I am pointing this out is because I did it as you did and it worked until I started to mass edit the documents with cloud functions. Your answer works, but it is not future proff.

Comment: Thanks to you both for the hearty debate -- yeah, I saw this in the docs and was hoping to avoid the key id before pushing @mmason33 but that might be what I need to do.

Comment: "the ID can be changed. Say that the author allows the user to write to the document. Then the user can overwrite the ID and then you already have the ID of the document when you are fetching it so no need to add another key with the ID when the document already has an id" -- good point, @CyrusZei, this is something I hadn't considered, but I'm just starting with firebase and hoping to keep it as simple as possible!